# Pug - pass json data from pug to pug

Tags: json, object, pug

What i want to do is to pass a json data and loop it in other pug, but there was some errors.

Pug 1

```
-
  var json = [
    {type:"2", shareTools:"true", id:12},
    {type:"1", shareTools:"false", id:20}
  ]
include pug2.pug
```

Pug 2

```
div.json #{json}
each data in json
    li= data.type
```

Here is the html output of div.json #{json}

```
[object Object],[object Object]
```

gulp error message

```
> 4| each data in json
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you get in console if you add this line just after `div.json`: `- console.log( json );`

Comment: it outputs the json data, [
    {type:"2", shareTools:"true", id:12},
    {type:"1", shareTools:"false", id:20}
  ]

Comment: Maybe, there is a case problem, that get JSON native object, try to rename your variable. Also try to always use semantic variables names over technical names.

Answer (score 2):

### Hi, hope this helps

Changed 2nd row in pug2.

#### Pug1

```
-
    var jsonnn = [
            {type:"2", shareTools:"true",
            id:12},{type:"1", shareTools:"false", id:20}
        ]

include pug2
```

#### Pug2

```
div.json #{json}
each data, i in jsonnn
    li= data.type
```

Answer (score 0):

From a style point of view, a mixin might be worth considering.

Pug1:

```
include mixin1
-
    var data_set = [
            {type:"2", shareTools:"true",
            id:12},{type:"1", shareTools:"false", id:20}
        ]
mixin1(data_set)
```

Pug 2 is the mixin:

```
mixin mixin1(data_set)
each data in data_set
    li= data.type
```

Comment: Caught a typo: the call to mixin1(data_set) in Pug1 should read +mixin1(data_set). Also, good form to store the mixins in a separate folder.